# How rails is handling the inheritance concept, parent accessing child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This raises an error "undefined method hi":

```
class A
  def bla
    hi
  end
end

class B < A
  def hi
    puts "Hii"
  end
end

a = A.new 
a.bla
```

I have a Rails application that does this:

```
class BlaParentController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :setting

  def create
    @random_obj = ParentRandom.create(permitted_params)
  end
end

class BlaController < BlaParentController
  private

  def setting
  end

  def permitted_params
  end
end
```

A method call `BlaController#create` goes to `BlaParentController#create`. But `BlaParentController` is accessing methods `permitted_params` and `setting` from its child `BlaController`. How this is possible?

Comment: Your second example makes no sense. What is `ParentRandom`? It would also be easier if you had classes that are intuitive as examples, e.g. `Animal`, `Dog`, `GermanShepherd`, where it is clear how inheritance works.

Comment: I am sorry it had to be this way .. but you can get the idea of parent class using the methods `permitted params and settings` of child class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ordinary methods, what matters is whether it is defined for the receiver. Other kinds of contexts (such as, from which method it is called) does not matter. (The few exception to this are methods like `Kernel#__dir__`, `Module#nesting`, `Exception#backtrace`.)

In the first example, the receiver is an instance of `A`, but not `B`. Hence it can access methods in `A`, but not those in `B`.

In the second example, the receiver is an instance of `BlaController`, which is a subclass of `BlaParentController`. Hence it can access methods in `BlaController`  as well as those in `BlaParentController`.